# PowerPC emulator for Windows/Mac OS X capable of running Mac OS 8.1

Tags: macos, emulation, powerpc, mac-os-classic

I have an old Mac OS 7 application written in Symantec Think C++ 8 which I'd like to resurrect.

I can run my old Mac OS 8.x image on Basilisk II exactly as it was at the time of development, including the extensions, environment and all the rest working perfectly, under Windows or Mac OS X on an Intel CPU.  But when I try to open the project file through 'THINK Project Manager' or 'Symantec Project Manager', I get this error message: `<name of the app> must be run on a Power Macintosh`.

Of course, Basilisk II does not emulate PowerPC! When I had a Wintel box as my desktop I spent a lot of time configuring PearPC -- it would run using the official Apple installation media but not install my development environment.  I can't seem to get "close enough" on either setup!

Is there a PowerPC emulator for Mac OS X Snow Leopard + Intel CPU that runs OS 8/9 fairly well? Will I need to reinstall from original media or will I be able to "convert" my Basilisk disk image and move it over?

Comment: wow.. a question where [osx] and [mac-os] are *both* appropriate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/

From the people that brought you Basilisk II  ;-)

Comment: I have followed your link and landed on: http://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/sheepshaver_mac_os_x_setup, thanks for the pointer! :) I am trying it in another window as I type. I'll report back if I succeed... otherwise... I'll just wait for more wisdom! ;)

Comment: Oh... BLISS... SheepShaver worked PERFECTLY for me! The JOY!!!